# Dynamic function in php

Tags: php, function, dynamic

Hello I am a beginner in php.
I've recently learned a bit about functions. But how do I dynamically insert data into the (). I've tried using get and post but that didn't work (Perhaps I just did something wrong). Any examples on how i could do it?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show what you tried and explain how it didn't work?  You can put any value you like into the function call...

Comment: You better post your non-working code, so that people can comment and fix it.

Comment: Please try and supply (pseudo) code that shows what you want.

Comment: Add small code that shows what you want to do.

Comment: How can one know what you did wrong if you don't include the code you've tried?

Comment: It looks like he is trying to put into the `function something($_GET['var1'], $_GET['var1']) { return 'something'; }` and to call ur `?var1=something&var2=different`

Comment: How can ppl seriously answer this question. You are just guessing. For me dynamic functions mean lambda functions, what does this have to do with get / post, we don't know.

Comment: Sorry folks I was typing on my phone so i didn't managed to write the whole code in. But I've solved my problem! Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

action.php

```
<form action="action.php" method="post">
 <p>Your name: <input type="text" name="name" /></p>
 <p>Your age: <input type="text" name="age" /></p>
 <p><input type="submit" /></p>
</form>
<?php

function myFunction($argOne, $argTwo) {
   echo "inside function argOne=".$argOne;
}

if (isset($_POST['name']) {
    //call the function only if the form is submited
    myFunction($_POST['name'], $_POST['age']);
}
?>
```

Comment: But how do i pass values from inputs etc.. to myFunction('a value', 'an other value');
?>

Comment: You should read http://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

Answer (score -1):

I think you want to pass some data to your function

The post just send the data to your php page.
If you want to send some data to your function you should do that as a parameter.

Example:

```
$myvar = $_POST;

dumpData($data){
   var_dump($data);
}
dumpData($myvar);
//OR
dumpData($_POST);
```

You can't just send the post to your function, you need to call that and use it as a param.

Comment: The person that did the -1 can explain why at least?